# Call method from Utilities class, an NSObject class to show the popup view in my view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiview

I just want to call the method from utilities class which is an NSObject class so that when it is called the popup view i want to show will appear.

I have an `UIView` which contains an `errorPopupView` that has to be shown on many screens. So, i want to create a method which can be called from any class to show the popup view. So, i created a `NSObject` class, which contains the method below.

And one more thing how this button action can be set, it should be in NSObject class or view controller.

Comment: First question: I didn't see the use of the parameter `restoreView` in the class method.

Comment: +(UIView *)restorePopupView:(NSString *)text andValue:(NSString *)value;

Comment: You want to pass some values to your restorePopupView: function right?

Comment: @Rushi I just want to call the method from utilities class which is an NSObject class so that when it is called the popup view i want to show will appear. But i don't know the right way of doing this.

Comment: your question is not really clear, what do you want to do with parameters ?

Comment: @iPhone6 what is the name of the class you have written restorePopupView function in.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(UIView *)restorePopupViewSetYourParameters:(NSString *)text anyOtherValue:(NSString *)value classForButtonCall:(id)callingClass;
```

When you have to call this just do :

```
[Utilites restorePopupViewSetYourParameters:@"Abcd" anyOtherValue:@"XYZ" classForButtonCall:self];
```

Comment: Can you tell about the content of method, or the way i did was ok like declaring the UIView, alloc, set frame and etc. was right.

Comment: @iPhone6 yes you can do that. It was clean. As you are using and calling from different classes you'll have to do it.